# how to add timer in ReactJS hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am trying to add timer, 
problem statement - when user click on button, it should call timer to start and after 3 seconds it should perform something.

my code which is not working

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(3);

useEffect(() => {
    if (timer > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => setTimer(timer - 1), 1000);
    } else {
      window.close();
    }
  }, [timer]);

function submitStartTimer(){                /*Button onClick=submitStartTimer()*/
    setTimer(3);
    swal({
      title: "Thank You!",
      text:
        "You have successfully Submitted your Data! This tab is going to close!",
      icon: "success",
      button: false,
    });
}
```

but the tab automatically gets close after 3 seconds, i know because of useEffect, but how can i start useEffect after click of submitStartTimer()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);`

You just have to start the timer with 0. Since you're starting with 3, `useEffects` kicks in and keep decreasing the timer right from the beginning because of this:

```
if (timer > 0) {
  setTimeout(() => setTimer(timer - 1), 1000);
}
```

As [timer] has been passed as a dependency, whenever this changes, `useEffects` is called and hence you're seeing the behaviour. You have already used:

`setTimer(3)` in your submit method so that should work provided you go with this: `const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);`

Another solution could be to remove `[timer]` from the dependency in `useEffects` and keep it [].

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, a little modification by using Rahul's answer help me to solve it.

```
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(-1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => setTimer(timer - 1), 1000);
    } else if (timer === 0) {
      window.close();
    }
  }, [timer]);

function submitStartTimer(){
  setTimer(3);
    swal({
      title: "Thank You!",
      text:
        "You have successfully Submitted your Data! This tab is going to close!",
      icon: "success",
      button: false,
    });
}
```